# How to include a tab in an Excel for Mac cell - Mac equivalent of char(9)

Tags: ms-office

I'm writing some guides for a procedure which involves using an Excel formula which places tabs into a cell. This guide will be used by staff on both Windows and Mac, and I want to make sure it works on both. I don't currently have access to a Mac for testing.

On Excel for Windows, `=char(9)` places a tab character. This tab character doesn't show within Excel, but does appear correctly when the content of the cell is copied and pasted, which is what I need.

Some of the Excel character numbering is different between Mac and PC, for example, [non-breaking space is char(160) on Windows and char(202) on Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179177/how-to-specify-non-breaking-space-on-mac-excel-mac-version-of-char160).

What's the Excel for Mac way to add a tab character by a formula? Specifically Excel-2011 for Mac, but I don't believe it changes between versions.

I've tried looking it up in this table - http://www.alanwood.net/demos/macroman.html - but that doesn't include the Tab character.

---

If it's possible, I'd love an option that works on both Mac and Windows and is standard to spreadsheet programs e.g. not just MS Excel but others too. But I'm guessing this is probably impossible, so just knowing the Mac exquivalent of `=char(9)` would be enough.

---

Bonus points for a link to a reference to the complete character table Excel for Mac uses so I can just look up any question like this in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, the TAB character on a Mac has the same ASCII code -- 9, so `=char(9)` should just work.