# How to insert a tab in a cell in Excel for Microsoft 365

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

For inserting a tab in a cell, I have tried the instructions from a few resources but none work. Here is one  from Microsoft Learn has options but they do not work:  [How do I indent in Excel 2011 for Mac?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-indent-in-excel-2011-for-mac/2a0a2031-fecc-40e1-a8f6-1116547d2306)

Also this one does not work:  [How to include a tab in an Excel for Mac cell - Mac equivalent of char(9)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201947/how-to-include-a-tab-in-an-excel-for-mac-cell-mac-equivalent-of-char9)

Note: I'd far prefer to have a shortcut way to do this operation instead of needing to hit ribbon, or menubar, or click on something else.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcut for inserting tab (Increase Indent) is Option-Control-Tab.

One way to find, assign and override existing keyboard shortcuts in Excel is Tools > Customize Keyboard. There is possibility to search for commands, see their current shortcuts and assign (if no keyboard shortcut exists) or override (change to personal preferences).