# In Mac Excel, how can I replace with newline?

Tags: mac, ms-office

In Mac Excel, how can I replace with newline?
Ex:
Finds all 
`AAA BBB` 
and replace all with
    AAA
    BBB

Please any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is newline ? are you trying to move data currently entered in coulombs to rows

Comment: @Buscar웃 in a single cell, i need to split it with line break

Comment: something like this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-line-break-in-a-cell-a918e875-625e-4510-86d7-9f5873fe21c7

Comment: are the AAA, BBB the same in the sheet

Comment: yeah in same sheet, but in many cells in a column

Comment: So you want a column containing rows that culd have rows of text inside them? It des sem odd it might be a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so more information could help.

Comment: @Mark I don't see this as an XY Problem because it's entirely plausible that the data in a single cell may be a long text type and that the OP wishes to persevere line breaks within them (i.e. "Full Address")

Comment: @Allan possible but that is why I said might

Comment: I have an update for you, see my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Manually Adding a Line Break

You can do this by pressing <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the point you want to insert the line break.

It's best that you format the cell(s) as *Text* to ensure the best results.

[image]

### Mass Insert Line Break (a.k.a Search/Replace)

You can do this on a mass basis with Search & Replace.  As before, it's important to **format your cells as text.**  In the replace field, use the generic formula

```
="Text1"&CHAR(10)&"Text2"&CHAR(10)"Text3..."
```

- The text to be replaced in quotes (" ")
- & as the `concat` (concatenate) function
- `CHAR(10)` as the symbol for `newline`

Using this methodology, you can "fix" multiple lines of text (like an address).  See the animation below for an example:

[image: Search Replace with Line Break]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what I need is not on a single cell. In the whole spread sheet, I have to find the existence of all AAA BBB and then replace it with  line break value. Hope the problem is clear now. I will edit the question.

Comment: In Word you have the option in Find/Replace to replace with a "special character" like a paragraph or newline character. Excel doesn't seem to offer that. Have you tried replacing your string with the "AAA BBB" plus the MS Word string for a new line (^|) character in the middle? Just spitballing here but often the things work across apps in MS Office apps.

Comment: [This question is related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179177/120171) and may provide some insight.

Comment: Brilliant! Never thought to set the cells as text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Find & Replace

[image]

How to find or replace a line break in Excel for Windows

To replace a line break with a space or any other separator, enter the line break character in the Find what filed by pressing Ctrl + J. This shortcut is the ASCII control code for character 10 (line break, or line feed).

After pressing Ctrl + J, at first sight the Find what box will look empty, but upon a closer look you will notice a tiny flickering dot like in the screenshot below. Enter the replacement character in the Replace with box, e.g. a space character, and click Replace All.
Replacing all line breaks on the sheet with spaces

To replace some character with a line break, do the opposite - enter the current character in the Find what box, and the line break (Ctrl + J) in Replace with.

[Excellent instructions found here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/09/29/using-excel-find-replace/)

[Finding the equivalent in Excel for Mac.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-for-mac-acf5419e-1f87-444d-962f-4e951a658ccd)

Since I do not have Excel to verify it here is what I found for you to try.

[image]

Comment: What I exactly want is what to type in "Replace with:"

Comment: @AJ see my updated post with instructions link

Comment: This appears to be for the Windows version, no? How about macOS?

Comment: @bjbk do you have better answer to help the OP, or you just intuitively feel like my answer is wrong.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I think you are on the right track. Just wondering if Excel for Mac is the same. Depends on the OP’s version I think. Cheers!

Comment: I have tested this, although the tutorial @Buscar웃 references is very good, it only works in the Windows version of Excel.  For some reason (control + J) does not work in the replace field, neither does replacing with the return character CHAR(10) as in Replace: ="AAA" & CHAR(10) & "BBB"  -- Good starting point though!

Comment: Just in case someone finds this and is wondering, the find/replace dialog in mac excel looks very different from the one in windows excel. The "format" and "options" buttons don't exist and there is no "look in" dropdown.