# How to replace newline in Excel for Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office

It seems there are suggestions for how to replace a character or a string with a newline in Excel for Mac, such as [In Mac Excel, how can I replace with newline?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338482/in-mac-excel-how-can-i-replace-with-newline). But trying to reverse the process does not work; e.g., to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> etc. Any advice on how to replace newlines in cells with, for example, space?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for some cases could be:

Copy cell(s) (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), paste special (<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), select **Values**, click **OK**.

Caveats: There must be space at the end of the line, otherwise there will be no separation between lines (it removes newline but doesn't replace); it doesn't work in-cell (source and destination cells must be different).

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Aivar Paalberg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/350043/aivar-paalberg) and thanks for the answer. This does not work, unfortunately. It seems that **Excel for Mac** has a very limited capability in that respect. I think that such things work better under **MS Windows**.

Anyhow, I managed to solve my problem with **Apple Numbers** where this becomes next to trivial: **Numbers** allows `\n` and one can replace it with whatever s/he wants.

Comment: This specific scenario (with caveats limitations) does work in Excel on macOS.